# combo box connect signal should not be triggered when the combo box is empty

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox

I have connected a combo box to a slot on currentIndexChanged value.

The issue i am facing is that when i clear all the items from the combo box than also the event gets triggered.

Whenever i clear all the items from the combo box i do not want the function to execute.

what i though of was to add a if condition when the number of elements of the combo box is 0 , but i could not find any member function in the combo box that would return the number of elements in the combo box.

If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

```
 connect(comboBoxFunctions, qOverload<int>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), 
 this, &WavefrontRenderer::AddContainerFunctionProperty);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to block the signals with [`blockSignals()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) while cleaning the QComboBox:

```cpp
comboBoxFunctions->blockSignals(true);
comboBoxFunctions->clear();
comboBoxFunctions->blockSignals(false);
```